# How to modify the time limit in the "Jet Appointment" plugin settings?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I'm working with the Jet Appointment plugin and need to add a locked time before each appointment. The plugin includes a dropdown list with a maximum time limit of 23:59, but I need to add more time.

Upon inspecting the code, I found the following template for the settings:

```
<cx-vui-time
    class="jet-apb-working-hours__main-settings"
    label="<?php esc_html_e( 'Locked Time Before', 'jet-appointments-booking' ); ?>"
    description="<?php esc_html_e( 'The appointment cannot be made if there is less than this time left.', 'jet-appointments-booking' ); ?>"
    :wrapper-css="[ 'equalwidth' ]"
    :size="'fullwidth'"
    placeholder="00:00"
    :value="getTimeSettings( 'locked_time' )"
    format="HH:mm"
    @input="onUpdateTimeSettings( {
        key: 'locked_time',
        value: $event,
    } )"
></cx-vui-time>
```

I noticed that the time limit might be controlled by the getTimeSettings() function located in the settings.js file. However, I couldn't find where the time limit is specified within that function.

```
getTimeSettings: function( key ) {
                    var dateObject = moment.duration( parseInt( this.settings[ key ] ), 'seconds' ),
                        minutes    = dateObject._data.minutes < 10 ? `0${dateObject._data.minutes}` : dateObject._data.minutes ,
                        hours      = dateObject._data.hours < 10 ? `0${dateObject._data.hours}` : dateObject._data.hours ;

                    return `${hours}:${minutes}`;
                }
```

Looking at the code, I ended up more confused, I honestly don't know where exactly the time limit is being controlled.

[I found this github link with the plugin files](https://github.com/danielslyman/pvsv-repo/tree/main/plugins/jet-appointments-booking)

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or code snippets that could help me.

Comment: Looks like that `getTimeSettings` function only fetches the currently stored value for the `locked_time` option, so that the corresponding value can be automatically pre-selected. I am guessing the 24 hour limitation might perhaps rather be "part of" the `cx-vui-time` component itself ...?

Comment: @CBroe Is it possible to modify the time limit in the <cx-vui-time> component? It Is there another file or module responsible for providing configuration options for this component? I'm unsure about how to adjust the time limit in this specific component and would appreciate more information or guidance on this matter. Thank you! –